# Key '1' not working after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, keyboard

I have a strange problem. After upgrading to 14.04 the button <kbd>1</kbd> on my keyboard has stopped working in the following way:

1. It does not matter if I use the built-in keyboard or an external keyboard.
2. It is only the top row key. The num pad still works.
3. Holding it down still works, but not tapping it quickly. (i.e. I cannot write only one <kbd>1</kbd>)
4. It still works if shifted
5. It does not matter what character map I use.
6. It still works in the login screen or when using a text-only tty.
7. If I have a searchbox or similar open, it will close from a quick tap of the button.

When running xev I get the following from pressing the button:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x94, subw 0x0, time 8764461, (480,-221), root:(480,361),
    state 0x0, keycode 10 (keysym 0x31, 1), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (31) "1"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I am stumped, and this problem is mking my everyday work rather complicated. Any pointers to where to check is most welcome!

Comment: Try installing `xdotool` (`sudo apt-get install xdotool`) then run `xdotool key 1`. Does that type it?

Comment: Nope. No output at all. (But when I use key 2 I do get the correct output)

Comment: Okay, open 2 terminals. In the first run `xev` then in the second run `sleep 3 && xdotool key 1` Then hover over the xev window and see what output xev gives...

Comment: `MappingNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248`

Comment: So, can anyone help me interpret what this means'

Comment: Can anyone help me interpret what this means? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is this problem still current?  If yes, could you go to TTY1, log in and type `showkey --scancodes`. and report back what you get when typing top row "1".  Still on TTY1, `showkey --keycodes` and report back too for top row 1. Then switch back to the GUI and run `xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'` and report back what you get when typing top row 1.  Afterwards, type keypad 1 and report back these too...